# how to bind the list to dropdownlist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0

I am calling a web method from a JavaScript function

```
      function loadstatecity() {
        alert(document.getElementById("CountryList").value);

       // PageMethods.username_availability(document.getElementById("CountryList").value, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
       PageMethods.loadstatecity(document.getElementById("CountryList").value, OnSuccess,OnFailure);
   }
```

Web method is returning a list of strings:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> loadstatecity(string countrycode)
    {
        utilityFunc.loadstatecity(countrycode);

        return utilityFunc.state;
    }
```

loadstatecity function Code:

```
     public static void loadstatecity(string CountryCode)
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mag_SDK"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand())
                {

                    com.CommandText = "Select ProvinceName from Province where CountryCode=@Country ;";

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", CountryCode);
                    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    while (!dr.Read())
                    {
                        state.Add(dr["ProvinceName"].ToString());

                    }

                    com.Connection.Close();
                    com.Connection.Dispose();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
}
```

Now I want to bind this list to a DropDownList.

How can I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The List of strings type returned in your C# method will be serialized into a JavaScript array and will be accessible in a JavaScript callback.  You'll then need to loop through all of the strings in the serialized array converting each one to an HTML 'option' element and then attach each element to the HTML 'state' select element produced by your ASP.NET.  Here's some code which should accomplish that:

```
// The function to run on success, adds options to the state select.
function success(response) {
    var select = document.getElementById('id-of-your-state-select-element'),
        index = 0,
        option = ''
        value = '';
    if (select) {
        for (index; index < response.length; index++) {
            value = response[index];
            option = '<option>' + value + '</option>';
            select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', option);
        }
    }
}

// Shows an error in an alert box, should be improved before 
// production deployment.
function error(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

These two functions are then used in your 'loadstatecity' method as success / failure callbacks.

```
PageMethods.loadstatecity(document.getElementById("CountryList").value, success, error);
```